# Find the free variables of $\phi$ and give an equivalent prenex formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Let $\mathbb{L}$ be the first order language where $C=\{c_1\}$ is the
> set of symbols of constant, $F = \{f^1_1,f^2_1, f^2_2\}$ is the set of
> symbols of function, $P = \{p^1_1,p^2_1\}$ is the set of predicate
> symbols, and consider the formula,   $\phi = (\forall x_1)
>  p^2_1(f^1_1(x_1),c_1) \implies ((\exists
>  x_2)p^2_1(f^2_1(x_1,x_2),x_2)\lor \lnot p^1_1(x_3))$
>
> a) If possible, give an example of a logically valid formula of
> $\mathbb{L}$ that contains the term $f^2_1$.

How do I know if the formula is logically valid if I have no idea what $f^2_1$ is? Do I have to define it?

> b) Indicate what are the possible occurrences of free variables in
> $\phi$.

$x_1$ and $x_2$?

> c) Determine, if possible, a normal prenex formula that is logically
> equivalent to $\phi$.

Same question as a).

> d) If possible, give an example of a formula $\psi$ such that
> $\mathbb{L}$ such that $\phi \vDash \psi$.

Same question as a).

Comment: a) $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 (f^2(x_1,x_2) = f^2(x_1,x_2))$. Do you know the def of *valid formula*?

Comment: b) NO; $x_1$ and $x_3$